# Mathematical Probability Problem

Tags: probability

Some friends and I were having an odd discussion about a hypothetical scenario. We couldn't come to a conclusion and as I believe the answer is based on mathematical probability I found this community hoping for a proven solution. I hope I have come to the right community for help.

The scenario is as follows (it is somewhat odd):
A person is having a shower and washing their hair with shampoo. This particular shampoo is somewhat deadly. The shampoo is running down your face and there is a 75% chance some will go in your eyes, and a 25% chance some will go in your mouth.
If the shampoo gets into your eyes, there is a 25% chance you will go blind. If the shampoo gets into your mouth, there is a 75% chance you will die.
You only have time to stop it from getting into either your eyes or mouth. Which would you choose to stop.
So our question is, of the 2 final outcomes, which, if either, is more likely?

In summary:

25% chance of A. If A, 75% chance of B.

75% chance of X. If X, 25% chance of Y.

Is either B or Y more likely overall?

I hope I have made the question clear enough. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The odds are exactly the same. Probabilities multiply. There is a

$$\frac{1}{4}\ast\frac{3}{4}=\frac{3}{16}$$

chance of both outcomes. Avoid death.

Comment: This is correct, assuming your events are independent (which it seems they are).

Comment: Thank you very much.